# Invalid field contact for SObject Account

Tags: apex, error

```
list<account> a=[select id,type , (select id ,name from contacts),name from account limit 5];

for(account ac:a){
    system.debug('account:'+ac);

    for(contact c:ac.contact){
        system.debug('contact:'+c);
    }
}
```

Comment: "test", it may be easier to help you if you include more precise information such as the error and why you're not sure how to advance. Having a better understanding of your problem will help us help you better

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
 list<account> a=[select id,type , (select id ,name from contacts),name from account limit 5];
   for(account ac:a)
    {
        system.debug(ac);
        for(contact c:ac.contacts)
        {
            system.debug('contact:'+c);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you are querying child records in the inner query. And to get all child records of a parent record you have to use the child relationship name as used in inner query.

So, instead of

> "for(contact c:ac.contact)"

use

> for(contact c:ac.contacts)

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

list a=[select id,type , (select id ,name from contacts),name from account limit 5];

for(account ac:a){
    system.debug('account:'+ac);

```
for(contact c:ac.contacts){
    system.debug('contact:'+c);
}
```

}